# Java list class methods from command line

Tags: java, command-line

Is it possible to get a list of methods of the class from command line?

In **Eclipse** or **Intellij IDEA** one usually hits `ctrl + space` for autocompletion menu. It's cool, but I wish to get something alike from **bash**.

E.g. I have a class that extends a class (or classes if the parent also extends a class) and implements a couple of interfaces - so I need to know which methods I'm able to use.

---

P.S. I use **vim** 'cause I have memory limitations to use entire IDE.

Comment: For c you could use cscope, I don't think there is such a tool for Java. You could probably write one. There is the, sadly not up to date, [Java Development Environment for Emacs](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: This wouldn't be very hard to implement yourself. You could write a Java program that uses `Class.forName(args[0]).getMethods()` and display them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the java disassembler: [`javap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javap.html):

> #### Example
>
> Compile the following `DocFooter` class:
>
> ```
> import java.awt.*;
> import java.applet.*;
>  
> public class DocFooter extends Applet {
>         String date;
>         String email;
>  
>         public void init() {
>                 resize(500,100);
>                 date = getParameter("LAST_UPDATED");
>                 email = getParameter("EMAIL");
>         }
>  
>         public void paint(Graphics g) {
>                 g.drawString(date + " by ",100, 15);
>                 g.drawString(email,290,15);
>         }
> }
> ```
>
> The output from the `javap DocFooter.class` command yields the following:
>
> ```
> Compiled from "DocFooter.java"
> public class DocFooter extends java.applet.Applet {
>   java.lang.String date;
>   java.lang.String email;
>   public DocFooter();
>   public void init();
>   public void paint(java.awt.Graphics);
> }
> ```

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know about `javap` disassembler and it's features. Thank for the hint. It does work like a charm on custom classes, but I also wished to disassemble *standard* Java classes (like e.g. ArrayList) to get fast-list of fields/constructors/methods (if it is possible).

Comment: The standard Java classes are all inside `rt.jar` and a jar file is just a zip file, so you can extract whichever class file you want and decompile it.

Comment: Severe decision, but it works. As far as I understood, `javap` can't read a class from *stdin*, can it?

Comment: @UmbraAeternitatis Just type `javap -private java.util.ArrayList` on the command line (or don't use `-private` if you don't want private methods/fields)

Comment: I tried to `javap ArrayList`, but... I failed to understand to pass full path.

Comment: You have to give the full name `java.util.ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

While I would advice spending a bit of money on more RAM, you could using ctags instead. I'm not sure if it's up to date with Java 7/8/9 features, but here's a blog describing how to use it: http://andrewradev.com/2011/06/08/vim-and-ctags/

Comment: `ctags` seems to be interesting tool. Perhaps I should try it - I can't get any effect from it for now. It's does not seem to be trivial.